# Integrate by parts $\int x^3e^{x^2}dx$

Tags: calculus, integration

> Integrate by parts:
>
> $$\int x^3e^{x^2}dx$$

I see a way by substitution, but I'm not seeing the integration by parts. Taking $u=e^{x^2}$ seems not to work, and I believe $e^{x^2}$ is not easily integrable. What am I missing?

Comment: Try $u=x^2$ and $dv=xe^{x^2}\,dx$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

David Mitra provided an answer in the comments:

> Try $u=x^2$ and $dv=xe^{x^2}dx$.

Answer (score 4):

Hint: Use the substitution $u=x^2$ and then try integration by parts.